# unexpected fault address 0x0 while using dll api

Tags: dll, go

I am trying to use some third party dll in go language. But facing enormous difficulties. I would prefer pure go implementation but that is not a choice.

This my sample program

```
import (
"fmt"
"github.com/andlabs/dl"
)

type GetObject func(string, string) int

func main() {
    gro := new(GetObject)
    d, err := dl.Open("/home/vaishnavi/lib/libVsphere.so", dl.Lazy)
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("DLL Loaded::", d)

    s, err := d.Symbol("GetSum")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    gro = (*GetObject)(s)

    p := (*gro)("1","2")
    fmt.Println("Got returned result::", p)
    fmt.Println("Converted::", gro)
    fmt.Println("Loaded at::", s)
    if s == nil {
        fmt.Println("Error loading from the dll")
    }

}
```

While running this program i am getting following error

```
DLL Loaded:: 15028848
unexpected fault address 0x0
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xb code=0x80 addr=0x0 pc=0x401923]

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.gothrow(0x4dcef0, 0x5)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:503 +0x8e fp=0xc20805fda0   sp=0xc20805fd88
runtime.sigpanic()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:29 +0x265 fp=0xc20805fdf0 sp=0xc20805fda0
main.main()
        /home/vaishnavi/ESXI_VHBS/src/main/main.go:25 +0x343     fp=0xc20805ff98 sp=0xc20805fdf0
runtime.main()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:63 +0xf3 fp=0xc20805ffe0     sp=0xc20805ff98
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1 fp=0xc20805ffe8 sp=0xc20805ffe0

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1
Error: process exited with code 2.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're ignoring the error from `d.Symbol("GetSum")`. What's in it?

Comment: I checked it in actual code. editing question now.

Comment: What kind of function is `GetSum`? What are the arguments and the return value? If it's a C function, shouldn't [C strings](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C) be used instead of Go strings? Also, have you tried doing it like in [the example](http://godoc.org/github.com/andlabs/dl), with a C wrapper?

Comment: True!I changed it to C strings using C.CString(""),it throws the same error.As you said I also tried using C wrapper,but it gives the following error                                                                                                                   fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0xc200000000 pc=0x7f12f851caea]

Comment: Please update the question to include the new code and error so that people could look at it.

Answer (score 2):

The [package documentation](http://godoc.org/github.com/andlabs/dl#Module.Symbol) says:

> Symbol looks up the given named symbol in the Module. **Note that the value of Symbol can be nil,** so checking symbol for nil will not indicate an error; checking err for nil is.

(Emphasis added.)

From the [package's source code](https://github.com/andlabs/dl/blob/796da005555675751ef0b7000963dd5b464f8e48/dl.go#L33) it seems that there are only two reasons both Symbol and err can be `nil`. Either the symbol is really null, or it doesn't exist in the library. Make sure that the symbol is really there, and that you've not misspelled the name. Usually you can list all symbols in an `.so` file with `readelf -Ws` or `nm -g`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!I get the error in the function call only...on commenting the function call...The output is as follows                                                                                                                            DLL Loaded:: 23405168
                     Converted:: 0x7ff0c768ef66
                     Loaded at:: 0x7ff0c768ef66                                                                                           So the symbol is present in the dll file,there are no issues in s being nil.